# Writing lists to columns in a CSV file using Python

Tags: python

I have the following list :

```
theList= ["ABCD","EFGH","IJKL","MNOP"]
```

I want to write this list to a CSV file as different elements in each column in a single row. The final CSV file should look like;

```
  -----------------------------
1 | ABCD | EFGH | IJKL | MNOP |
  -----------------------------
```

I tried the following code (with csv library), but it writes to multiple rows instead of columns

```
tempRows = zip(theList)
    with open("Final.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        for tempRow in tempRows:
            writer.writerow(tempRow)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling `zip` and then iterating over it? It should suffice to call `writerow` directly with `theList`.

```
with open("Final.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(theList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the parameter list directly to writerow?

```
writer.writerow(theList)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put each item into a list within theList, you can write to a single row:

```
theList= ["ABCD","EFGH","IJKL","MNOP"]
theList = [[string for string in theList]]
out_file = r"E:\data\one_line.csv"

with open(out_file, "w", newline="") as data:
writer = csv.writer(data)
for sub_list in theList:
    writer.writerow(sub_list)
```

Comment: Obviously, you'll need to change "out_file" to the path and filename you want.